# Mudar instalador de pacote padrão

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, yarn

É possível mudar o **package** padrão de instalação de `Yarn` para `NPM`?

Erro que está apresentando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Você não deu muitas informações sobre o problema, não apresentou código, e a imagem postada não diz praticamente nada a respeito do caso.

Porém é possível que no arquivo package.json a propriedade packageManager esteja definida como yarn e na máquina de execução, o yarn não esteja instalado/habilitado.

Segue info sobre a definição do packageManager no package.json:
https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-package-manager

Comment: No caso eu gostaria de mudar o package manager padrão, do yarn pro NPM. Quando eu crio um proejto Angular, ele sempre busca instalar o yarn como package. Tem alguma forma de mudar isso?